# Best way to show a subset of fields base on use case

Tags: forms, user-expectation, design-patterns

I am rewriting a user interface for an application that generates licenses. Currently the interface is one page with all possible fields and check boxes for licences/license combinations. The goal is to streamline the license generation for 2 particular use cases, but still have all of the options accessible.

The two use cases allow us to default many of the fields/checkboxes.

What is the best design pattern for displaying this?

Options I am currently considering:

1. Tabs for each use case which shows only the non-defaulted fields for
   each use case, last tab has all fields/checkboxes.
2. Show all of the options but have a radio button at the top to pick which use case. Then some of the fields could be defaulted/filled-in based on the selected use
   case.
3. Similar to option 2 but dynamically hide the defaulted fields
   for depending on which use case is selected.

Comment: I like #2. I think it's important to see the values of the defaulted fields, to confirm I'm making the appropriate selection.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood you correctly.I have created quick mockup around the problem. It may need further redesigning and testing with end user to validate the idea. I advise you to test with users.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, ask the user which use case they fit into.

Then, take them through a form with all defaulted options or options they need to fill in.

Make sure to specify why certain options are pre-filled or uneditable. Maybe include text above the field: "We've pre-selected this option based on your select of "